# How to remove pinching effect when scaling a 3D object

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

I have an object that I imported from an STL file and I'm trying to scale the side of it.  When I select the region I want to scale and drag along the x axis I get this crease or pinching effect.  How do I get rid of it?  It seems to be caused by a large concentration of edges.  Do I subdivide this somehow?  The STL file I imported this from is not mine.  Is there an addon that would remodel this object a higher resolution of subdivison of faces?  The only thing I can think of to do would be to add more verticies and manually relink those edges to better space them out but that seems tedious and I'm wondering if there is a existing tool that could do this?  Thanks.[image]

Comment: Maybe try a remesh modifier?

Comment: Hello Chris.  Thanks for the suggestion!  I just had a look at that modifier and it looks like the solution I need.   I guess I have to remesh and decimate to the desired "resolution", right?  Is there a better remesh modifier than the built in one?

Comment: The first ones that come to mind are RetopoFlow and DyneRemesh but those cost money. You could also try this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmuSgMqPQkk - this is a link to a video outlining version 1 of this addon. There is a version 2 (link below the video), but there seems to be more community confusion about getting it to work than there is with Version 1. Other than that, some combination of remesh, decimate, and manual re-topology should get you pretty close to what you need.